# Select Query with multiple results

Tags: sql, select

I would like to display multiple results in a single line separated by a comma.

Please use this SQL Statement for the sample data set:

**DECLARE @TBL_EXAMPLE table
(
[ID] varchar(50),
[Category] varchar(25)
)
INSERT INTO @TBL_EXAMPLE ([ID], [Category])
VALUES
('1234', 'Manager'),
('1234', 'Sales'),
('345', 'Sales'),
('6467', 'Manager'),
('6467', 'Sales'),
('41234', 'Sales'),
('41234', 'Manager'),
('91234', 'Sales'),
('1234', 'Admin');
select * from @TBL_EXAMPLE**

Result should display like this :

ID     | Category

1234   | Admin, Manager, Sales

345    |Sales

41234  |Manager, Sales

6467   |Manager, Sales

91234  |Sales

Comment: Depends on which DBMS you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in MySQL:

```
    select id, group_concat(category separator ', ') as categories
    from tbl_example
    group by id
```

Here's the format for PostgreSQL:

```
    select id, string_agg(category, ', ') as categories
    from tbl_example
    group by id
```

Other DBMS will have something similar (search for string aggregate).

Results:

```
    id      categories
    1234    Manager, Sales, Admin
    345     Sales
    41234   Sales, Manager
    6467    Manager, Sales
    91234   Sales
```